# How to transparent primeng table

Tags: css, angular, transparent, primeng

I was using primeng DataTable and i want it background transparent 
I've tried

```
<br>
[style]="{'background':'transparent'}"<br>
[style]="{'background':'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}"
<br><br>
```

and both of them doesn't work

here is the table template with white background

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [style]="{'background':'transparent'}">
<p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
<p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
<p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
<p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Can anyone tell me how to transparent the primeng table :) ?

Comment: Have you tried background-color instead of background ?

Comment: `background` is not a valid CSS property. It's a shortcode to set multiple CSS properties at once, but it only works in CSS, not in `JavaScript`. `[style]="{backgroundColor:'transparent'}"` should work. Or, `[style]="{'background-color':'transparent'}"`. For any current browser, they're the same thing. However, I don't know anything about primeng. I'm just assuming `[style]="whatever"` will work, since you seem to expect it to work.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu both of them doesn't work , thx for you reply QQ

Comment: @KCarnaille  yes , i tried

Comment: Maybe you have to style the row too. What if you show your Data table without data? Is the background transparent in this case?

Comment: @zgue even fi the data table empty, it still not transparentQQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `styleClass` property.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="values" styleClass="someStyleClass">
...
</p-dataTable>
```

Then go in your root `styles.css` and do this:

```
.someStyleClass .ui-widget-content
{
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

`styleClass` will make sure that only the DataTable with `someStyleClass` has the `background-color:transparent` applied to its content.